# Access INSERT INTO SQL Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

Having trouble with my insert into sql.  All the code below works, excep the SQL strings that add a value for level.  Here is my onclick code for a form with three boxes.  The table that stores the pH, Temp, and Level values has a number format with field size 'single' set for all three fields.

Again, if I leave the 'level' box blank, it works!  But when I try to insert a level value, with any other combination of values, it fails.

Code Below:

```
Private Sub SubmitSampleData_Click()
Dim pH, Temp, Level As Single
Dim TodaysDate As Date

TodaysDate = Date

If IsNull(Me.pH.Value) Then
    pH = 1
Else
    pH = Me.pH.Value
End If
If IsNull(Me.Temp.Value) Then
    Temp = 1
Else
    Temp = Me.Temp.Value
End If
If IsNull(Me.Level.Value) Then
    Level = 1
Else
Level = Me.Level.Value
End If

If Level = 1 And Temp = 1 And pH = 1 Then
     Exit sub
ElseIf Level = 1 And Temp = 1 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, pH) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & pH & ")"
ElseIf Temp = 1 And pH = 1 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, Level) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & Level & ")"
ElseIf Level = 1 And pH = 1 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, Temp) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & Temp & ")"
ElseIf Level = 1 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, pH, Temp) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & pH & ", " & Temp & ")"
ElseIf Temp = 1 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, pH, Level) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & pH & ", " & Level & ")"
ElseIf pH = 1 Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, Temp, Level) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & Temp & ", " & Level & ")"
Else    
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, pH, Temp, Level) VALUES (#" & TodaysDate & "#, " & pH & ", " & Temp & ", " & Level & ")"
End If

MsgBox "Submit Successful!", vbOKOnly, "Success!"

Me.pH.Value = Null
Me.Temp.Value = Null
Me.Level.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you not using parameterized queries?

Comment: Ignoring the not using parametrized queries, what is the datatype of Level in your database?

Comment: datatype of level is number with size single

Comment: What is the error you get? Not an answer to your question but very important: Have you heard about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: Error "Syntax error on INSERT INTO Statement"

Comment: The syntax is identical to the lines that work!  Only the lines that add a value for level cause an error...

Comment: Can you post the entire error message? And the SQL that causes it (which line). Also, please read on SQL injection.

Comment: The error may be due to the value of the level. What is the value of "level"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Saying "error" and "fails" is meaningless, without also explaining what error you're getting or in what way it fails. The first thing you should do after typing either of those words (or "exception") should be to start typing the **exact** error or exception message you got (including any memory addresses) or a description of the way it's failing. Please remember when posting here that we can't see your screen or read your mind, and we don't know what you mean by "fails" or "error" unless you share that information. Thanks.

Comment: @Nivas Ms Access is much less prone to SQL injection and is not generally used in situations where sql injection is a problem, however, it is important to ensure that data is clean.

Comment: The Exact Message is as follows: Run-time error '3134': Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Level is a reserved word and must be enclosed in square brackets.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO SampleDataQuery (DateCreated, [Level]) VALUES (#" _
   & TodaysDate & "#, " & Level & ")"
```

Reserved words

[Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) 
[ACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, the field name could be changed to something else, like "lvl"

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  This worked perfectly!!  I did not know that Level was reserved, I will change this immediately!  WOW!!  Wonder where a list of all of the reserved words can be found.  THANKS AGAIN!!

Comment: @PowerUser There is a rule that says don't use abbreviations, so pHLevel, say, would be better. I have no idea why a suggestion to lvl would be voted up.

Comment: I used TankLevel and it is now working flawlessly!  Thanks for the links of reserved words!  There are a bunch more than the 10 or so I knew about....